# ReplaySubject read all values

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, replaysubject

I am trying to read all emitted values of a replaySubject.

```
selectedPersons = new ReplaySubject();
sub = new Subscription;
--
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.selectedPersons.subscribe((resp) => {
  console.log(this.selectedPersons)
  console.log(this.selectedPersons._events) <--- This one doesnt work because its private but i need this values
}) 
}
--
onSelect(value: Person) {
   this.selectedPersons.next(value)
}
```

Data will be emitted in this Subject and i want to read all its values, not only the last one. What is the best approach to do ?

I want to display this data then in the html with | async

Answer (score 1):

I assume every time new event comes you want to get all the events that arrived before. to achieve it you can use `scan`

```
this.selectedPersons.pipe(scan((prev, evnt) => prev.concat(evnt), [])).subscribe((resp) => {
  console.log(resp); // all events will be here
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The values that `selectedPersons` emits can be seen in the lambda function you give to `subscribe`.

```ts
this.selectedPersons.subscribe(resp => console.log(resp));
```

In this case, the emissions are called `resp`. So that's what you would need to log.

You can call them whatever:

```ts
this.selectedPersons.subscribe(persons => console.log(persons));
```

---

If you need all previous emissions during each emission, you can do that like this:

```ts
this.selectedPersons.pipe(
  scan((acc, v) => [...acc, v], [])
).subscribe(allPersons => console.log(allPersons));
```